# MySQL relation table - how to make it smaller?

Tags: mysql

I am making a POI option in our website, using a POI table with ~14 million rows. I would like to connect these POIs with data from another table, which contains roughly 2 million rows(they are ads).

I tried to make a third table(a link table), which stores the relations between the "ads" and the "POIs", but the table is VERY HUGE. (~600 million rows and still counting). This third table contains only 3 rows, a UNIQUE identifier, ad_id and poi_id. Is there any other way, to store such a simple relation, which is not so resource intensive?

**EDIT**

I am thinking about reordering my POIs by latitude, and recreating their ID's, and afterwards store the relations in the table the following way:

```
relation_id   ad_id   poi_start_id   poi_end_id
```

where poi_end_id can be null, if it is, only poi_start_id is related, if not, everything between poi_start_id and poi_end_id is related.

What do you think, would this fasten search in the huge table, and make the table size smaller?

Comment: If you can have more than one ADS by POI, it is the only way to create the relations. But, with well indexed ID fields (covered indexes), it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Don't know if it could fit your model, but you could also group your ADS in a new table (by region? type? locations?) and use the group in the link table instead of directly your ADS.

Comment: I don't know, wouldn't this result in large amount of data that is irrelevant for my query? What I am trying to achieve, is to show every POI in a let's say 5 mile radius around a specific point.

Comment: Did you take a look at MySQL geospatial extensions? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html